# When updating react native app on play store, still showing Uninstall and Open option. Not showing Update option

Tags: upload, react-native, package.json, google-play-console

I am Uploading a new version app on play store but, still, they showing uninstall and open options. How to change this option. Or any change in react native package.json file like version.

Comment: has the review process for the update been concluded?

Comment: hi did you got any solutions ?, I also got the similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, both the Google Play Store and Apple App Store usually take some time to review and process updates. If you check the Google Play Store dashboard, you'll get a notification once your update goes live, you'll then be able to see the 'update' button.